In primeng 17 if the value set in p-calendar and [maxDate] are same then the value is not showing
here is the demo i made in stackblitz ,
https://stackblitz.com/edit/nb7yxf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcalendar-minmax-demo.ts
I tried to bind the date value in p-calendar it works for every date except it matches with the date set in [maxDate]. For example if the [maxDate] is set to 31st december and if the date value in the p-calendar is 31st december then the value is not showing in the p-calendar (priemng 17).

You are not using Java Sever Faces

You can use the data as temp: any = '2024-12-31T00:00:00';
It can be the timezone issue.

Or you can use the maxDate to the end of the day, because you specified only date month so hours and minutes are 0 means its the start of the day so any hours after that will be not allowed. You can use maxdate as :
this.maxDate = new Date(year, 11, 31,23,59,59,999);
